# Using the Prototype and Constructor Properties of JS in conjunction

Tags: javascript

From what i understand,a Prototype object is an object from which other objects inherit properties and methods,and basically it holds a Constructor Property that Refers to or points to the Constructor function that created the Object.Please Consider the Following Code:

```
function Animal()
{
this.name="no name";
}

function Cat()
{
    Animal.Call(this);          //Please Explain
    this.mood="sleepy";
}

Cat.prototype=new Animal();     //Cat inheriting Animal?
Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;  //Please Explain
```

Please explain clearly but in details the code lines with comments and the concept of reflection,thanks.

Comment: You probably mean `Animal.call(this);`. And what exactly do you want to have explained? What `.call` does? Why it is there? Or what? Btw, a better to set up the prototype is `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);`. At that moment in your code, you don't want to create a new `Animal` instance.

Comment: yes i'd like to know what's the Purpose of `Animal.call(this)` and    `Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;` thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the Purpose of `Animal.call(this)`

It's like calling `super()` in other programming languages. It calls the parent constructor (`Animal`) on the just created new object (`this`). This is also explained in the [MDN documentation about `.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

In your example, `Animal` assigns `"no name"` to `this.name`. So after calling `Animal.call(this);`, `this` will have a `name` property with the aforementioned value.

> and `Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;`

By default, each prototype's `constructor` property points to the function it belongs to. But since you overwriting the prototype with `Cat.prototype=new Animal();`, the `constructor` property points to a different function now. In this case, since `new Animal` returns an object that inherits from `Animal.prototype`, `Cat.prototype.constructor` will point to `Animal`. To fix that, we assign `Cat` again.

Strictly speaking this is not necessary since the `constructor` property is not used in any internal function. However, if your code relies on it, it has to be set to the correct value.